# Python - help() command - same string different results

Tags: python

I'm using the python help command with the same string but it's giving different results.

The code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

link = BeautifulSoup("bilateralFilter")
title = link.getText()

string = "cv2." + title + ""
string2 = "cv2.bilateralFilter"

if string == string2:
    print "----- Output 1 -------------"
    print(type(string))
    help(string)
    print "----- Output 2 -------------"
    print(type(string2))
    help(string2)
```

Console output:

```
----- Output 1 -------------
<type 'unicode'>
Help on unicode object:

class unicode(basestring)
 |  unicode(object='') -> unicode object
 |  unicode(string[, encoding[, errors]]) -> unicode object
 ...
----- Output 2 -------------
<type 'str'>
Help on built-in function bilateralFilter in cv2:

cv2.bilateralFilter = bilateralFilter(...)
    bilateralFilter(src, d, sigmaColor, sigmaSpace[, dst[, borderType]]) -> dst
```

So if it is the same string the help shouldn't be returning the same?

Comment: Are you sure you assigned `string2 = "cv2.bilateralFilter"` and not `string2 = cv2.bilateralFilter`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, I'm getting the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `title` is a `unicode` object.
2. Therefore `"cv2." + title + ""` is also a unicode object.
3. `help` apparently only accepts non-unicode `str`s for looking up names, such as `string2`.
4. So `string` and `string2` are in fact different types, but `str` and `unicode` can still compare equal.
5. You can reproduce the behaviour with `title = u'bilateralFilter'` or `string = u"cv2.bilateralFilter"`.

Comment: It's true! Also if I do `string = str("cv2." + title + "")` it gives the same result

Comment: @JoãoCartucho this is a classic case where you can solve the problem yourself if you try creating a [mcve] before posting a question.

Comment: @JoãoCartucho no problem

Comment: @JoãoCartucho yes, that's a good MCVE. Next step debugging would have been `print(type(string))` or `print(repr(string))`.